# Regarding Facebook Registation/Login on website

Tags: authentication, facebook, facebook-like, registration

Is it possible to have the user "like" your page during the registration process using the Facebook Registration/log in function on my website.  I know you can have custom fields, but I don't see anything that talks about this.  Please tell me where I can find this information.  I don't want to be repetitive on my website by having them do this twice.

Answer (score 0):

Authenticating an application is not the same as liking an application.  So they are two distinct things.  You can create something called a fan-gate to prevent the user from seeing the good stuff if they don't like your app.  Google fan-gate and you will see some examples of how to implement.

Comment: DMCS. Thanks so much for answering my questions.